What is this around my fluid? (weight map?)

I'm trying to figure out how to work with fluids and so far no youtube tutorials had this colourful thing around their liquid. It's there even if I press z and select rendered view.

These are the domain's particles generated by the fluid simulation, by default they are visible only in the viewport and the color gradient represents the velocity.
You can leave it on, it's quite useful for inspecting your work, they will not be visible in final render.
But if you want to change their display settings or turn them off, you can do so by going to the domain object's particles settings:

If I were you, I would just reduce the display size to fit inside the mesh. But if you want to turn them off, you can set the Display As to None.

Thank you!!
You're a life saver!
